# error: could not find an overload for'init'that accepts the supplied arguments double (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have some problems  with this error,I'm a beginner
I will be very happy if you help me 
I try more variants but it didn't work

```
var x:Double = 0 


@IBAction func digitals(sender: UIButton)
{

    println("Cifra\(sender.tag)")
    if enterFlag == 1 {

        x = 0
        enterFlag = 0
    }


    if decimalPoint == 0
    {
        x = x * 10 + Double(sender.tag)

        self.result.text = " " + String(Int64(x))
    }
    else {
        x = x + Double(sender.tag)/pow(10, Double(power))
        power++
        self.result.text = String(x)  ===> error

    }


}
```

thank you very much for your advice ! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no intializer to convert `Double` to `String` but
You can convert `Double` to `String` by

```
self.result.text = "\(x)"
```

You can use this way to convert any basic datatype to `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a Double to a String.

You could use:

```
self.result.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", x)
```